# change the language of my main page

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a website http://www.apisnatura.com  with the modulle MULTILINGUAL - INTERNATIONALIZATION.

I manage to create the pages of each language and when i click any language icon the main menu changes and the rest of the pages also change.

My question is... how do i change the main page content after clicking the different language icons with the relevant language.

I been looking around and i am getting crazy looking for a solution.

Any help will be great to carry on changing the content for this web.

Cheers

Comment: How is the content that is not being translated being displayed on the front page? With a View? block?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have activated these modules.
Views translation and  Block languages (i18n_block).

Then You need to change those blocks language settings in configuration. follow this: https://www.drupal.org/taxonomy/term/39286

tick "make this block translatable" and select the languages.
it will allow you to translate a block in to a language you want. you might need to create separate blocks for each language.

In a View check if "Field Language" selected as "Current user's language" in Advanced area.

also use a filter for the view "Content: Language (= Current user's language)"

This will populate the content by detecting the users selected language.
"